# Multiple keyboards -- ignore one

Tags: linux, xorg, python, keyboard

I want to have two keyboards connected to my computer, from two different USB ports, of course.

One shall work normally, but the other one I don't want the system to collect input from. That one I shall manually read using a Python script.

How would I do this?

Comment: Aside from using Python to manually read it, is there a way to disable one keyboard without making it unaccessible?

Answer (score 1):

After hours of searching, I decided that `IOCtl(xxx,EVIOCGRAB,1)` was going to solve my problem.

Documentation here:

[Disable keyboard but still allow reading from it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/343305/disable-keyboard-but-still-allow-reading-from-it)

[Disable or redirect keystrokes from keyboard](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/disable-or-redirect-keystrokes-from-keyboard-4175480091)